# What is the opposite of "parallel" in architecture?

Tags: single-word-requests

The two towers of the Verrazano Bridge are not parallel: they are slightly [???] to account for the curvature of the earth.

[image]

What is that word?

Comment: They are slightly sloped

Comment: divergent perhaps

Comment: "Angled" is a simple way to express it.

Comment: Yes, but "sloped," "divergent," and "angled" - all of them would have to be qualified (i.e. "rather than parallel"). Is there a technical term that actually means "non-parallel"?

Comment: @Ricky You gave us an example sentence which already included 'not parallel'. If you want to be able to dispense with 'not parallel' you need to rewrite your example sentence and include all relevant information in the question. However, any word that describes non-parallel lines and that **cannot** be applied to *parallel* ones should meet the case. 'sloping' lines can still be parallel as it doesn't specify that they slope differently e.g. the uprights of a leaning ladder can slope but remain parallel, but a ladder cannot have convergent side pieces that are parallel to each other.

Comment: I’d say they are slightly ***oblique***.

Comment: @Jim: Good one.

Comment: they are [splayed](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/splay)

Comment: They are tilted (away from each other).

Comment: You can say: "There is a slight curvature of the earth between them.". The towers are vertical actually but not parallel to each other.

Comment: Why would anyone downvote this one? Goodness.

Comment: @Jim Isn't 'oblique' about not being perpendicular? And these towers *are* perpendicular, at right angles to the plane of the horizon, or to a tangent touching the horizon at a given point. It's the curve of the earth that allows them to both have that perpendicularity yet not be parallel. If you poke a straw through an orange both ends will be perpendicular (with luck!) to a tangent to the orange's curve, but they wouldn't be parallel.

Comment: @Spagirl - *oblique*:  Neither perpendicular nor parallel.  The towers are at a slightly oblique angle to each other to account for the curvature of the Earth.

Comment: @Jim Ah, you didn't say 'to each other' and I read it in relation to their base. Though it seems slightly 'remote' to refer to their angle in relation to each other which iss o acute that they won't meet for nearly 4,000 miles. :)

Comment: @Spagirl - That’s exactly the degree to which they are not parallel that started the whole discussion. :-)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/84054/discussion-on-question-by-ricky-what-is-the-opposite-of-parallel).

Answer (score 10):

I believe it's as simple as "nonparallel". A synonym for this is "oblique" ("slanting or inclined in direction or course or position--neither parallel nor perpendicular nor right-angled").
https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/nonparallel

Comment: Oblique is not right for the towers.

Answer (score 9):

The *opposite* of parallel is right, orthogonal, normal or perpendicular. But these towers are not the *opposite* of parallel, they're simply not parallel. So you could just say "not parallel". You could also say "at an angle to each other". Technically, parallel lines are at angle of 0, and 0 is a number, but people will know what you mean. You could also say they "diverge" or "are divergent". Here, it would be implicit that they diverge as one goes up.

Comment: I guess I would be wrong to say they converge or are convergent.

Comment: @Stan If you look at what happens when you start at the top and go down, they do converge, but I think it's more natural to treat things as "starting" at the ground and going up.

Comment: Oh, I gathered that mention of the centre of the earth was some sort of reference. It's not important.

Comment: The opposite of parallel is *intersecting*...which includes lines that are perpendicular(etc.) but also includes a whole bunch of other lines.

Comment: @user3067860 No, the *negation* of "parallel" is "intersecting". The opposite of x is not everything that's not x, it's whatever's *most* not x. For instance, for relations, the opposite of symmetric isn't non-symmetric, it's anti-symmetric.

Comment: Can you to cite any geometry reference that says perpendicular is the OPPOSITE of parallel? Perpendicular is just a special form of intersection. Anything that is not perpendicular by definition intersects at some point in space. Asking a question about the opposite of parallel is really a form of double negative, which is also by definition an ambiguous phrase.

Comment: @Acccumulation  _"the negation of 'parallel' is 'intersecting'"_ - this is true only if the lines are coplanar. If there is no plane that contains both lines then they can be both nonparallel and nonintersecting.

Answer (score 8):

Use of a **descriptive word** along with "**parallel**" seems appropriate here - adverbs like *almost, approximately, virtually, or visually*.

The nature of the construction and the deviance from parallel is so small that using a completely different word would seem to convey greater difference than is actually present.  The two bridge towers are almost (but not quite) parallel, differing, top distance vs. base distance, by a small but significant 41.26 mm. They are:

"**virtually**" parallel. or "**approximately**" parallel

or

They "**deviate**" from being truly parallel.

> Example: Though **virtually** parallel, they actually **deviate** from parallel by 41.26
>   mm at top to correct for the curvature of the earth.

https://www.thefreedictionary.com/virtually

https://www.thefreedictionary.com/deviate

Comment: _near-parallel_ was what I was thinking. Not catchy, but accurate and descriptive.

Answer (score 5):

I think you could go with ***[askew](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/askew)***:

> out of line :  at an angle
>   <sub>from *[m-w.com](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/askew)*</sub>

Comment: "The two towers of the Verrazano Bridge are askew." Hmm ...

Comment: Askew has the connotation of “out of position” and not by design to me.

Comment: @Jim, The full sentence "The two towers ... are slightly askew to account for the curvature of the earth" reads fine, implies the direction of the 'askewity', and negates the "not-by-design" connotation.

Comment: Yeah, that makes it better.

Comment: @Jim to an architect, I don't think that would be true. *askew* is used in architecture simply to mean "not orthogonal". It doesn't necessarily have a negative connotation.

Comment: Note: "askew" or "skew" in the geometry of three dimensions means that the two straight lines to which the relation is assumed to exist do not share a common point, no matter how far the two are projected.

Answer (score 3):

They are **divergent** or **diverging**

> Drawing apart from a common point; diverging. ([Free Dictionary #1](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/divergent))

Answer (score 3):

"Angled".  But, uh, in your picture it is clearly the pincushion distortion of the lens that is doing a much more thorough job of sabotaging parallelism than Earth curvature (the radius is something like 4000mi after all).  And after pincushion distortion, there is perspective distortion.  And of course you'd not make the pillars of a suspended bridge vertical anyway but angle them outwards so that the combined load of their weight and the rope tension will point towards their foundation.

Comment: Excellent analysis.  Made me chuckle.

Comment: the towers are 1 5⁄8 in (41.275 mm) farther apart at their tops than at their bases; they are not parallel to each other. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Verrazano-Narrows_Bridge#Statistics Yes, angled outward.

Answer (score 2):

Divergent seems sensible to me

Comment: You say? Infinitely?

Comment: Or "convergent", even.

Comment: Your effort to help is welcome. To show that yours is the right answer, it should include explanation, context, and supporting facts. For example, you could offer evidence such as the definition from a good online dictionary. You could contrast your answer with other answers. Whatever would make this the right answer, instead of an opinion. This is what makes answers useful – to the asker, and to future visitors. See: “[Real questions have answers, not items or ideas or opinions](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/01/17/real-questions-have-answers/)”.

Answer (score 2):

In electricity the opposite of "parallel" is "series" relative to connections. It would also apply to these towers as they appear in series along the bridge roadway.

Comment: That's quite witty, dude!

Answer (score 2):

there are many good answers here for what you want, but technically none of them are the opposite of parallel. that would be perpendicular or orthogonal

Answer (score 2):

If the word "parallel" is used in the computational process, or some other process task, you can use "serial" as oposit of "parallel".

- Example 1:

  My computer can process 8 tasks in parallel.

The oposite

My computer has an serial processor.

- Example 2:

  My team can perform 10 process in parallel (i.e. in the same time)

The oposite

My team can perform only processes serially

Answer (score 1):

Although it doesn't quite fit into your sample sentence, the word ***radial*** describes the tilted arrangement of the bridge towers:

> Of or arranged like rays or the radii of a circle; diverging in lines from a common centre.
>   <sub>[Oxford Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/radial)</sub>

Comment: +1, but it would not hurt to make it clear that the center referred to is the center of gravity (centroid) of the earth.

Comment: @SenexÆgyptiParvi: The towers would have to be perpendicular to the earth's surface for that to be true. Given the length of the bridge, the tilt would not be very noticeable, and the towers would appear to be parallel. More likely, the tilt of the towers is governed by the arch of the bridge itself. The bridge is likely arched to allow it to handle more weight.

Comment: @jxh - Speaking as a bridge engineer: for a suspension bridge you wouldn't tilt the towers in order to arch the bridge, as the tower and the bridge deck can meet at any angle. Rather, you would make the towers vertical in order to ensure that the load is purely axial, rather than introducing eccentricity which would cause additional moments. As covered in the question "the towers are [not parallel] to account for the curvature of the earth": this exactly means that the towers are perpendicular to the earth's surface.

Comment: @AndyT: That makes more sense, but the photo does make it look like the towers tilt away from each other.

Comment: @jxh - Probably just perspective. As you say: *"Given the length of the bridge, the tilt would not be very noticeable"* - per [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Verrazano%E2%80%93Narrows_Bridge) the towers are only 41mm further apart at the top than the bottom. Although, given that article states that the towers are 211m high, 41mm horizontal sounds less then the construction tolerance (i.e. I'd be surprised if they could build the top to within 50mm of where it's supposed to be). This 41mm sounds theoretical rather than practical to me!

Comment: @AndyT: It must be an optical illusion, since the towers have to be erected first.

Comment: @jxh - And thinking on that: Even if they build the towers perfectly vertical (and hence 41mm further apart at the top than the bottom), as they stress the cables and add the weight of the bridge deck, the towers will sway. Given the difficulties in perfectly calculating the weight of the deck in advance, the chances of ending up perfectly vertical at the end of construction are minimal.

Comment: My suspicion: the towers ended up not perfectly vertical, which is normal and probably within the tolerance, but in order to allay public fears they explained it away as "due to the curvature of the earth". (Massive apologies for going completely off topic!)

Comment: @jxh \ You are correct on all counts.

Comment: @AndyT \Thank you for your informative commentary. The bridge with which I am most familiar is the Jefferson National Expansion Memorial in St. Louis.   :-)

Answer (score 0):

"Converging" would the most apt descriptor for "not parallel" in my opinion, as geometrically speaking any lines which are not parallel can accurately be said to converge or diverge.